# Qual é a grafia correta: "shampoo" ou "xampu"?

Tags: ortografia, uso-de-palavras, estrangeirismos

Sempre me deparo com esta dúvida e gostaria de esclarecê-la.

Comment: Não há nenhuma questão de estar gramaticalmente correto, senão ortograficamente correto.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Shampoo*** é uma palavra inglesa, mas reconhecida em dicionários do português, como o [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=shampoo), [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/shampoo), Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), e ainda na [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) e no [Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum da CPLP](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=137910).

A palavra portuguesa no Brasil é [***xampu*** (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/xampu), enquanto em Portugal é [***champô*** (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/champ%C3%B4).

E pronto, estes são os factos. Eu, num texto em português, parece-me melhor usar a palavra portuguesa. Mas cada um é senhor de si.

Nota que apesar de *xampu* ter uma pronúncia próxima do inglês *shampoo*, e *champô* não andar lá muito longe, o dígrafo *sh* não faz parte da grafia portuguesa; *oo* até faz, mas não para representar o som /u/.

Answer (score 6):

Durante muito tempo li a palavra *xampu* escrita como "shampoo" nas revistas e comerciais de televisão brasileiros. Em determinada época que não sei especificar, ocorreu a normatização ortográfica e todas as palavras tomadas como empréstimo da língua inglesa, e escritas com "SH", passaram a ser escritas com "X" em pt-BR, passando então a ser classificadas como estrangeirismos.

> [**A forma correta**](http://comoescreve.com.br/xampu-champo-ou-shampoo/) no Português é apenas a expressão Xampu porque Shampoo consiste na expressão em inglês e Champô é a expressão deste produto no português de Portugal.
>
> A origem desta expressão é na palavra Shampoo sendo um estrangeirismo na rotina da Língua Portuguesa sendo Xampu a forma aportuguesada criada para a sua indicação tendo como base para sua criação a pronúncia desta palavra bem como as regras da língua do país.

referência referente à grafia "xampu" - Novo Dicionário Aurélio da Língua Portuguesa, 2ª edição, Editora Nova Fronteira.  A grafia "champô" não consta nas entradas do dicionário.

Comment: Que língua é essa do texto que você cita? Por que português é que não é.

Comment: @LuísHenrique   Foi a citação que encontrei na ocasião.  Concordo que está muito mal redigida e confusa mas, infelizmente, é português sim.  E tu sabes que é. :-)