# Qual a melhor ou correta gráfia para expressão show, ou xou?

Tags: ortografia

- Por que não temos a grafia da palavra *show* em português?
- Não poderíamos simplesmente escrever xou?

Pela mesma justificativa que escrevemos a palavra xampu que traduz a expressão *shampoo* [(clique aqui)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3913/qual-%C3%A9-a-grafia-correta-shampoo-ou-xampu)

Comment: Bem, até temos: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xou_da_Xuxa

Comment: Existe algum significado de _show_ que faça valer a pena aportuguesar a palavra? Porque no mais é só um anglicismo para programa ou apresentação.